# Bootstrap 4 Modal Close Icon Border (Background/Frame)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.0. I reduced the height of Bootstrap modal by half. Now when I click the close icon on top right corner, a weird looking (I don't know what it is) squarish looking border/frame appears. This is how that ugly thing looks like:

[image]

How do I get rid of this? Given a choice I would prefer "Pure CSS" solution. Thanks.

Update:

This is what I used but did not work.

```
.close {
    color: ghostwhite; 
    opacity: 1;
    border:0px solid #fff;
    outline:none;
}
```

As per Umesh's comment below, this fixed it for me:

```
.close:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: That icon wrapping Close button or link apply border none css OR outline none css.

Comment: Close button wrap icon in <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> element just call css to class named .close border:0px solid #fff and outline:none

Comment: Can you please add snippet.

Comment: It's button or link if button use 
.close:focus {outline:0;border:0px solid #fff;
    outline:none;}